# Fabric and Digits pods failing workspace in Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I updated to Xcode 7 and fixed the necessary code (syntax) changes for Swift 2.0. I updated my Podfile with these 2 entries:

```
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Digits'
```

and now see many build errors (pasted below). Any ideas?

I ran `sudo gem install cocoapods` to update my Cocoapods, and then ran `pod install` and `pod update` in order to install 'Fabric' and 'Digits' pods.

Note: Prior to updating to Xcode 7, my project, which uses Digits, was building and working correctly!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABJLObjectDeserializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTUserNetworking.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FABJLObjectSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TFSScribe", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRAPIResponseValidator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTNetworkingHelper.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRAuthConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRColorUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAppearance.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRCoreLanguage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRDictUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTLogInAuthConfiguration.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTDeviceRegisterConfiguration.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRGuestSessionRefreshStrategy", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRKeychainWrapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTSessionMigrator.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRNetworkingPipeline", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTNetworkingHelper.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRResourcesUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTURLSessionConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTResourcesUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRScribeClientEventNamespace", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRScribeEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRScribeService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRSessionStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRURLSessionDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTNetworkingHelper.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRUserSessionVerifier", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTSessionVerifier.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRUtils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAuthViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTConfirmSignUpViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTConfirmLogInViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTUploadContactsViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTConfirmViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTContacts.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TwitterNetworking", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTUserNetworking.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTContactsNetworking.o)
      objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
  "_TWTRAPIURLWithPath", referenced from:
      -[DGTUserNetworking verifyUser:completion:] in DigitsKit(DGTUserNetworking.o)
      -[DGTOAuthSigning OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentialsWithParams:] in DigitsKit(DGTOAuthSigning.o)
      -[DGTContactsNetworking uploadContactVCards:completion:] in DigitsKit(DGTContactsNetworking.o)
      -[DGTContactsNetworking lookupContactMatchesWithCursor:completion:] in DigitsKit(DGTContactsNetworking.o)
      -[DGTContactsNetworking destroyAllContactsWithCompletion:] in DigitsKit(DGTContactsNetworking.o)
      -[DGTAuthNetworking registerDeviceWithPhoneNumber:withVerificationType:completion:] in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
      -[DGTAuthNetworking confirmAccountWithPhoneNumber:confirmationNumber:completion:] in DigitsKit(DGTAuthNetworking.o)
      ...
  "_TWTRCoreOAuthSigningOAuthEchoHeaders", referenced from:
      -[DGTOAuthSigning OAuthEchoHeadersForRequestMethod:URLString:parameters:error:] in DigitsKit(DGTOAuthSigning.o)
  "_TWTRCoreVersion", referenced from:
      +[Digits assertValidTwitterCoreVersion] in DigitsKit(Digits.o)
  "_TWTRNetworkingErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[DGTAuthViewController startLogInProcessWithVerificationType:] in DigitsKit(DGTAuthViewController.o)
      -[DGTConfirmSignUpViewController startSignUpProcess] in DigitsKit(DGTConfirmSignUpViewController.o)
      -[DGTConfirmLogInViewController startLogInProcess] in DigitsKit(DGTConfirmLogInViewController.o)
      -[DGTPinCodeFormViewController startVerifyPINCode] in DigitsKit(DGTPinCodeFormViewController.o)
  "_TWTRNetworkingUserAgentHeaderKey", referenced from:
      +[DGTURLSessionConfig defaultAdditionalHeaders] in DigitsKit(DGTURLSessionConfig.o)
  "_TWTRScribeClientEventNamespaceEmptyValue", referenced from:
      -[DGTScribeViewEventLogger viewDidShow] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeViewEventLogger.o)
      -[DGTScribeViewEventLogger viewDidSucceed] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeViewEventLogger.o)
      -[DGTScribeViewEventLogger didShowFailureView] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeViewEventLogger.o)
      -[DGTScribeViewEventLogger errorDidOccurWithCode:] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeViewEventLogger.o)
      +[DGTScribeViewEventLogger scribeViewNameWithScribeView:] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeViewEventLogger.o)
      +[DGTScribeEventLogger digitsUniquesImpressionNamespace] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
      +[DGTScribeEventLogger digitsImpressionNamespace] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
      ...
  "_TWTRScribeEventImpressionClient", referenced from:
      +[DGTScribeEventLogger digitsEventNamespaceWithComponent:element:action:] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventImpressionPage", referenced from:
      +[DGTScribeEventLogger digitsEventNamespaceWithComponent:element:action:] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
  "_TWTRScribeEventUniquesClient", referenced from:
      +[DGTScribeEventLogger digitsUniquesImpressionNamespace] in DigitsKit(DGTScribeEventLogger.o)
  "_TWTRUserSessionVerifierDefaultDelay", referenced from:
      -[DGTSessionVerifier startVerification] in DigitsKit(DGTSessionVerifier.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't included 'TwitterCore' into the pod file:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Digits'    
pod 'TwitterCore'
```

Comment: Was this a recent change by Twitter? Previously (as in, prior to Xcode 7 upgrade), I was using pod 'Twitter/Fabric' and everything was working fine. If you could point me to these changes regarding Digits framework, that'd be helpful - thanks!

Comment: It worked fine because you had used old version of this pod. But after Fabric 1.2 all frameworks have become separated.

Comment: I have added TwitterCore too, but its not working for me. Any suggestion .. I am using Xocde 6.4